# Почему "биологически активный" пишется раздельно?

Tags: орфография

Я понимаю, что это слово из разряда "стратегически важный", то есть тут имеются два самостоятельных слова. Но все равно, когда приходится писать "биологически активный" очень хочется написать слитно - ведь это словосочетание давно уже слилось в одно понятие. Мы даже часто говорим "биоактивный". Скажем так, смысловое разделение этих слов давно потерялось, и просто логичнее было бы писать это словосочетание одним словом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это терминологическое сочетание, сравнить: химически чистое вещество, математически точное решение, микроскопически малое животное.

Здесь раздельное написание наречий, обозначающих область проявления признака или отношение, в котором рассматривается признак.

Термины с наречиями на СКИ и слитным написанием  не встречаются.

Сложные прилагательные, образованные  с помощью  иноязычных элементов, пишутся слитно: активный - биоактивный, народный – антинародный, красный  – инфракрасный.

Answer (score 0):

Это сочетание наречия с прилагательным всегда пишется раздельно, например: очень хороший. В данном случае, конечно, термин. Во-вторых, биоактивный пишется слитно, потому что слова, начинающиеся на *БИО* всегда пишутся слитно: биолог.

Answer (score 0):

Активный (в каком отношении?) биологически.
Написание раздельное.